# python doctest & coroutine

Tags: python, doctest

I am having a bit of trouble with `doctest` and coroutines...

```
def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr=func(*args, **kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    start.__name__=func.__name__
    return start

@coroutine
def leader_tracking():
    """
    Tracks 'leader' status - only returns transitions

    >>> lt=leader_tracking()
    >>> print lt.send(False)

    >>> print lt.send(False)

    """
    last_status=False
    result=("nop", None)

    while True:
        status=(yield result)

        if status!=last_status:
            direction="up" if last_status==False else "down"
            last_status=status
            result=("tr", direction)
        else:
            result=("nop", None)
```

If I use the usual doctest scaffolding:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

`doctest` doesn't show anything whilst if I use a more brute force method:

```
lt=leader_tracking()
print lt.send(True)
print lt.send(False)
print lt.send(False)
print lt.send(True)
print lt.send(True)
print lt.send(True)
print lt.send(True)
print lt.send(False)
```

I can see the expected result:

```
('tr', 'up')
('tr', 'down')
('nop', None)
('tr', 'up')
('nop', None)
('nop', None)
('nop', None)
('tr', 'down')
```

What am I doing wrong with `doctest` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The doctest module looks at docstrings which are stored in the `__doc__` attribute of a function.  Your coroutine decorator only copies `__name__`, so the docstring gets lost and doctest can't find it.  You could manually assign the `__doc__` attribute, but a better way is to use the functools module:

```
import functools

def coroutine(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return start
```

The `functools.wraps` decorator copies all the various metadata attributes of `func` into the wrapping function `start`, including the docstring, so that doctest will work as expected.

Also note that your doctest comment should include the expected output in order to work properly:

```
@coroutine
def leader_tracking():
    """
    Tracks 'leader' status - only returns transitions

    >>> lt=leader_tracking()
    >>> print lt.send(True)
    ('tr', 'up')
    >>> print lt.send(False)
    ('tr', 'down')
    >>> print lt.send(False)
    ('nop', None)
    """
    last_status = False
    result = ("nop", None)

    while True:
        status = yield result

        if status != last_status:
            direction = "up" if last_status == False else "down"
            last_status = status
            result = ("tr", direction)
        else:
            result = ("nop", None)
```